# Extension to manage product increment value PER group role

Tags: qty-increment

Our site sells B2C but also B2B with different group roles within those main headings.  We would like to be able to set (under Advanced Inventory/Qty Increments) specific increments per group - for example a General B2C customer could orders 1 of an item, but a B2B wholesale customer can only order in increments of 20.

I have searched for a suitable extension to achieve this but have had no luck so hence reaching out here to see if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to set per product Or global configuration for all products ?